# Muted video fails to autoplay when inserted into HTML via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I am trying to insert a HTML5 `<video>` element through Javascript, but it fails to autoplay despite it being **muted**.

#### Background Context

I would like to transfer all of my gif assets over to mp4 format. Likewise, I would like to have the HTML `video` emulate a gif. It should include the following properties:

- Be muted
- Autoplays as soon as the webpage loads
- Loop indefinitely
- Plays in line

I am currently on Chrome 100.

#### What I've Tried

Relevant code is held [within this codepen](https://codepen.io/t123278/pen/ExoqxYb?editors=1111). I want to add the HTML video dynamically through javascript. But this fails to autoplay even though both autoplay and muted attributes are specified.

However, if I have the video element with the same attributes directly written within the HTML, the autoplay functionality works just fine.

---

How do I insert the video with JS *and* get it to autoplay?

Comment: Please post code as a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could rather set attributes like this :

```
const anchor = document.querySelector('#anchor');
const vid = document.createElement('video');
anchor.appendChild(vid);
vid.autoplay = true;
vid.loop = true;
vid.muted = true;
vid.playsinline = true;
vid.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
```

Try to make these modifications. If it still not working, you could add this inline after above code :

```
vid.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Chrome is ignoring the `muted` attribute set before the media has loaded. The video is auto-played if the `muted` attribute is set when the media is loaded and can be played, which can be checked with the `canplay` event listener.

```
vid.oncanplay = () => {
    vid.muted = true;
    vid.play();
}
```

With this, you can ignore setting the `autoplay` and `muted` attributes initially.

```js
const anchor = document.querySelector('#anchor');
const vid = document.createElement('video');
vid.setAttribute('loop', '');
vid.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4');
vid.oncanplay = () => {
    vid.muted = true;
    vid.play();
}
anchor.appendChild(vid);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="anchor"></div>
```